# Q&A Power BI, No direct way to plot multilayer map

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to plot a multilayer map in PowerBI using natural language processing.
Let's say I write something like show total sales by state, district, postal code by map to show sales at the state level first then when I click on state drill down it to the district and so on.

Is there any way to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by plotting a multi-layer map using natural language processing. Do you mean that you would like to use the "Ask a Question" button in Power BI and you hope to get a map in return?

You could just create a map using your requirements. The best one to use would be the ArcGIS map.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no (built-in) way to drill down from a state level to a postal code level in Power BI.

You can however, display either a Us or State map with a Postal-Code level of granularity. Check out this thread:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Choropleth-using-3-digit-US-zip-code/td-p/74982

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses I already have these charts created in power bi from visuals directly but I am interested in creating drillable charts using ask your question query.